# Reason for broken pipes

Tags: python, networking, pipe

I'm writing a peer-to-peer program that requires the network be fully connected. However, when I test this locally and bring up about 20 nodes, some nodes successfully create a socket to other nodes, but when writing immediately after a broken pipe error occurs. This only happens when I start all nodes one right after the other; if I sleep about a second I don't see this problem.

I have logic to deal with two nodes that both open sockets to eachother, which may be buggy, though I do see it operating properly with less nodes. Is this a limitation of testing locally?

Comment: A peer-to-peer program where the connections need to form a complete graph? I hope you intend this to be a tinker toy

Comment: Also, when you create "two nodes that both open sockets to eachother", are you making sure you're opening the listening sockets before any one node connects? As you mention, you should sleep for a moment until all the listening sockets are open

Comment: I'm not, but the socket is being created, it's just that a broken pipe exception is thrown when writing to it.

Comment: Indeed, if the sockets were not yet open by the OS, you would get a "connection refused" error. But if you're saying it works when you sleep, it sound's like not everything is yet setup. Do you sleep between opening each listening socket, or before the writes?

Comment: I'm sleeping between starting each instance, so probably between opening the sockets.

Comment: Also, I'm not getting a "connection refused," the connection completes, it's just that sending the message results in a broken pipe.

Answer (score 3):

'Broken pipe' means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. So, you must have done that somehow.

Answer (score -1):

A "Broken Pipe" error occurs when you try to write to a pipe that has been closed on the other end. This could be handled ed if you're running a script like this if you are creating your own sockets:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('', 2020))


try:
    s.recv(1024)
except socket.error as e:
    print e
    print

s.send('hello')
```

This code works fine for me for this kind of errors. As Broken Pipe could be ignored if connection is reset/terminated by client.

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client1.py", line 17, in
    s.send('hello')
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: In this circumstance it would be more to the point to stop after the recv() method rather than just continue with the send() after any possible EOS or error as though it hadn't happened.